# Removing a tuple from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples that look like this;

```
ListTuples = [('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.102'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.103'), ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.100')]
```

I want to remove the tuples when the first element of the tuple matches the second element of another tuple and at the same time, the second element of the tuple matches the first element of the same other tuple. The OutputList will look like this;

```
OutputList = [('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.102')]
```

Is there an easier way to do this besides iterating through all the tuples to compare and saving to a new list of tuples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make two sets: the first has the original tuples, the second has the tuples with the elements swapped.  Then take the intersection of the two sets.  These are the tuples to remove.  Make a new list with all of the tuples but those:

```
>>> ListTuples = [('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.102'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.103'), ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.100')]
>>> set1 = set(ListTuples)
>>> set2 = set((e2, e1) for e1, e2 in ListTuples)
>>> to_remove = set1 & set2
>>> to_remove
set([('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.100'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.103')])
>>> NewList = [t for t in ListTuples if t not in to_remove]
>>> NewList
[('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.102')]
```

This will be O(n), whereas searching the lists will be O(n**2).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to iterate over your tuples if you want to compare them with one another, but at least you can use a temporary set with reversed elements for faster lookups:

```
ListTuples = [('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.102'),
              ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.103'), ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.100')]

seen = set()
for element in ListTuples:
    if element in seen:
        seen.discard(element)
    else:
        seen.add(tuple(reversed(element)))
OutputList = [tuple(reversed(element)) for element in seen]

print(OutputList)  # [('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.102')]
```

It will not keep the order, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `collections.Counter` to count the number of times each sorted tuple occurs, and then filter out those tuples that have a count greater than one:

```
from collections import Counter

ListTuples = [('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.102'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.103'), ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.100')]

counts = Counter(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in ListTuples)
OutputList = [k for k in counts if counts[k] == 1]

>>> OutputList
[('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.102')]
```

Note that this will not preserve the order of items in the original list; I don't know whether that is important to you in this case.

Also it is a little inefficient as it sorts each tuple, but something has to be done to take the item order into account, and if in the general case there can be more than 2 elements per tuple, sorting the tuples would be the way to go.

You can make it a one-liner like this:

```
OutputList = [k for k, count in Counter(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in ListTuples).items() if count == 1]
```